# AngularJS Unit Tests with jQuery.panzoom

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I would like to write some unit tests around my directive that is dependant upon jQuery.panzoom

For example I initialise the plugin within my directive like so:

```
 ...

 function init(options) {
      element.panzoom(options);
      panZoom = element.panzoom("instance");
 }

 ...
```

However, when I run the tests panZoom is undefined. I'm not sure how to setup jQuery.panzoom within my tests. I can't import it as it's not a module.

Any guidance would be great.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Within the test itself I mocked out jQuery.panzoon with the functions I cared about:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
    scope = _$rootScope_;
    compile = _$compile_;

    mockPanZoom = {
        matrix : [],
        reset : function(value) {},
        setMatrix : function(m) {
            this.matrix = m;
        },
        getMatrix : function() {
            return this.matrix;
        }
    }

    jQuery.fn.panzoom = function() {
        return mockPanZoom;
    };
    spyOn(jQuery.fn, 'panzoom').andCallThrough();

    ...

}));
```

Comment: any reason why you put underscores around injected dependencies?